# Print pdf from browser which generated with Mozilla Pdf Js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pdf, mozilla

I recently used [Pdf JS](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) to view pdf, is there a way to print all documents with this script, or there are other ways to print these documents?

Actually, we could use `window.print` javascript, but in Pdf JS I view my pdf page by page, so it's impossible to use `window.print` to print the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not implemented, but the feature is being tracked on bugzilla as https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748935

Cheers,

jonathan

Answer (score 0):

That old bug was closed years ago, current PDF.JS as framed viewer in a browser has no problems printing via the included print button, exactly the same as any other restricted print request, it will trigger the browser client users printing function:-

[image]